# Is it possible to use both L and E letters to initializing 'Long' numeric literal?

Tags: java, literals

If I declare a `long` variable as:

```
long n = 1E+12L;
```

The compiler throws a syntax error.

And when I declare it as:

```
long n = 1E+12;
```

It throws an incompatible types error.

On the other hand, it is happy to accept two letters in floats and doubles:

```
double n = 1E+12D;
float n = 1E+12F;
```

Why is it not working for `long` literals? do I have to drop the L letter and cast it to `long` every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The use of `e` or `E` in a numeric literal (i.e. [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)) is not allowed by the Java Language Specification for [integer literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-IntegerLiteral):

```
IntegerLiteral:
  DecimalIntegerLiteral
  HexIntegerLiteral
  OctalIntegerLiteral
  BinaryIntegerLiteral

DecimalIntegerLiteral:
  DecimalNumeral [IntegerTypeSuffix]

...

IntegerTypeSuffix:
  (one of)
  l L
```

It is allowed for [floating-point literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-FloatingPointLiteral), but these cannot have an `l` or `L` suffix:

```
FloatingPointLiteral:
  DecimalFloatingPointLiteral
  HexadecimalFloatingPointLiteral

DecimalFloatingPointLiteral:
  Digits . [Digits] [ExponentPart] [FloatTypeSuffix]
  . Digits [ExponentPart] [FloatTypeSuffix]
  Digits ExponentPart [FloatTypeSuffix]
  Digits [ExponentPart] FloatTypeSuffix

ExponentPart:
  ExponentIndicator SignedInteger

ExponentIndicator:
  (one of)
  e E

...
```

So, you either have to cast from `double`, or write out your `long` literal in full. For convenience, though, you can use underscores to group the digits, like `1_000_000_000_000L`, in order to make the number of zeros clear.

Comment: Java drives me up the wall sometimes, I mean what could possibly prevent such implementation!

Comment: It's the same in other languages, for example in C++ and Python, `1e3` is the floating-point number `1000.0`, not the int `1000`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why is it not working for long literals?**

`E` or `e` are not allowed to be used with an `int` or `long`. You can use them only with `float` or `double`

Please check the following text from the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed using E or e (for scientific notation)

**do I have to drop the L letter and cast it to long every time?**

Yes